# can I reduce executable file size by defining funtions in source code?

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, compiler-theory

In interpreted languages like python I can reduce the size of scripts by defining functions inside it.
In the languages like c, c++ can I use the same trick to reduce the size of executable file(not the source file)?
Does the compiler compile the part which includes the function only one time or does it repeat it at every time when the funtion is called in the source code?

Comment: The compiler may choose to "inline" function code if it is short to avoid the overhead of a function call. But generally the code of a function will be present only once in the executable.

Comment: Most compilers have an optimize for size flag that can reduce executable size.

Comment: "*In interpreted languages like python I can reduce the size of scripts by defining functions inside it.*" I don't understand this statement. If you don't define function in scripts, then what do those scripts *contain*? How does adding things to a script reduce the size of that script?

Comment: @NicolBolas I think OP means "I can make the length of a script smaller by breaking its tasks into separate functions rather than one long function in the entire script"

Comment: Nicol Bolas I meant if I have to type same stuff of the code at many places inside the source code then i can define a function including that stuff and call them on need. Then I can reduce the number of code lines Nicol Bolas

Comment: @GovindParmar Breaking a function into separate functions by itself doesn't make the length of the source code smaller.  Refactoring it into *reusable* functions would (which I'm sure is what you meant and which is what the OP is asking).

Comment: @jamesdlin right.

Comment: @KavinduRavishka It sounds like you are starting to suboptimize even before your functions have been written. Write good solid understandable functions and let people in your vicinity take a look at them and compile with "optimize for smallest size" turned on and look at the machine code.
Then, hand optimize it, compile and look at the machine code.
Compare how much you gained.